# VB.NET ASP.NET Web Application. Advice on getting ready for deployment

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was hoping for some advice on the correct approach to get my asp.net vb.net web application project completely ready for deployment. I recognise that I switch to release mode and compile. So I have my server-side code successfully compiling into a .dll file in the BIN folder, this is exactly what I want.

The issue where I am unclear is with the aspx.vb files and the aspx.designer.vb files that are attached to the .aspx files, I am using VS2010. I want to remove all of these from my project so that any of our potential clients have no direct access whatsoever to any of the server side code.

I have decompiled the .dll file and can see that it is all in there so I am fairly certain if I remove the code behind files the program will run without any difficulties. As I have never done this before I was hoping for some basic tips. Is this the correct approach to take? If so is there a standard good approach for removing the aspx.designer.vb files and the aspx.vb files from a given project within Visual Studio, or is it a case of manually taking them out of the release mode?

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: just use the `Publish` option to deploy to a file-folder - you will find everything you need in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code behind files are compiled into the dll in a web application so you don't need to deploy the .vb files (nor do you want to).

The dll is not obfuscated by default so anyone could decompile it to see your source however. There are free and non-free obfuscators available but that is outside the scope of this question really.

The easiest way to deploy is to [use visual studio to do this for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) <s>(I think you might need pro version or above)</s>

You can set up your own test web server locally and deploy to that first to see which files are in there.